# A generic function in C# that take a List of random class and an array of certain property names as parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a generic function that can print any certain property values. One parameter is a list of random class, another parameter is an array of certain class property names. The function is able to print given property value of each element in the list.
Assuming I have two classes of two lists of them:

```
class visitor {
    public string name;
    public string age;
    public string address;
    public string nationality;
}

class menu {
    public string dish;
    public double prise;
    public string chef;
    public bool isForVIP;
}

List<visitor> visitorList, List<menu> menuList
```

Now I want only the function `void GenericOutput(List<AnyObject> objList,string[] certainProperties)` to output a part of each class properties. For example:

```
GenericOutput(visitorList,new string[]{ "name","age" });
GenericOutput(menuList,new string[]{ "dish","double","isForVIP" });
```

How can I design the function in C#? Could some help me?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need to look at reflection, and `GetFields`, to achieve this

Comment: Either use Reflection (which is unsafe), or learn how to use `System.Linq.Expressions`.

Comment: What is the **actual** problem you're wanting to solve, btw? What you're doing does not have many legitimate users (outside of developer tooling), but it looks like you're writing an end-user application...

Comment: @canton7 I don't know how to set the type of the list in the function definition. `List<object>` does not work. Or maybe I should try List<T>? For getting the property value I was thinking to use `obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj).ToString()`.

Comment: `GenericOutput<T>(List<T> list, string[] names)`

Comment: @Dai I wasn't aware that Linq can do such work. I used to use it to get value from a list of known class. I am in a WPF project that we need to work with lots of different classes and we always need to output property values. That's why I am think to design a function that enables us to do so without caring the type.

Answer (score 1):

By using reflection, you can:

1. Create a generic method.
2. Get the run time type from the generic type argument.
3. Get information about the properties of the type.
4. Extract the values from each object of the type.

Example:

```
public void GenericOutput<T>(List<T> objects, string[] propertyNames)
{
    // Get the generic type.
    Type type = typeof(T);

    // Get the requested properties of the type.
    var propertyInfos = propertyNames.Select(pn => type.GetProperty(pn));
        
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            // For each given object, iterate the properties of 
            // the type and get the property value from the object.
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
            // Print or do whatever with the value...
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should cache the `PropertyInfo` objects btw. Consider using a `static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string,PropertyInfo>` within a `static class ReflectionCache<T>` to take-advantage of .NET's geneircs monomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var visitors = new List<Visitor>() 
            { 
                new Visitor(){Name="Visitor1",Age="30",Address="adress1",Nationality="Nationality1"},
                new Visitor(){Name="Visitor2",Age="20",Address="adress2",Nationality="Nationality2"},
                new Visitor(){Name="Visitor3",Age="10",Address="adress3",Nationality="Nationality3"},
                new Visitor(){Name="Visitor4",Age="50",Address="adress4",Nationality="Nationality4"},
                new Visitor(){Name="Visitor5",Age="90",Address="adress5",Nationality="Nationality5"},

            };
            GenericOutput(visitors, new string[] { "Name", "Age", "Address" });
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void GenericOutput<T>(List<T> obj, string[] properties)
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                foreach (var propName in properties)
                {
                    var propValue = (t.GetProperty(propName).GetValue(item) ?? string.Empty).ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{propName}:{propValue}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            }
        }
    }
    class Visitor
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:

[image]